# Badge/Flair for careers website

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I just signed up with Careers 2.0, and I have a Public profile. Is there any way I can create a badge saying *View my Profile on Careers*?, like the one which LinkedIn offers. Stack Overflow offers a `Flair`, which has the reputation and badges along with the name.

I am just wondering whether a similar option is available in Careers?
I have gone through the FAQ of the website, but could not find anything related.